# pdfkit [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pdf, pdfkit

I would like to convert an `HTML` page into a PDF file, based on the given URL. I have tried `pdfkit`, but it throws the following error:

`[WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation.`

Code:

```
import pdfkit
path_wkthmltopdf = "D:\\w.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path_wkthmltopdf )
pdfkit.from_url("http://www.google.com", 'd:\\out.pdf', configuration=config)
```

Output error:

```
n [42]: import pdfkit
path_wkthmltopdf = "D:\\w.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path_wkthmltopdf )

pdfkit.from_url("http://www.google.com", 'd:\\out.pdf', configuration=config)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-42-58323936ac63>", line 5, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_url("http://www.google.com", 'd:\\out.pdf', configuration=config)

  File "C:\Users\31081\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 26, in from_url
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)

  File "C:\Users\31081\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 129, in to_pdf
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "C:\Users\31081\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\31081\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\31081\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

Comment: Hey @Abhishek, did you ever solve this problem. I'm encountering the same

Answer (score 2):

I encountered with this problem too, I solved it by running .exe after run this it will create new dir, go inside this dir then bin dir you will find a exe file there like
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe
So, replace "D:\w.exe" to above kind of path in your code then it will work

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause

You are most likely getting that error as a result of downloading the **Installer** version, but not installig it. Thus, when running your code with `wkhtmltopdf` in the configuration pointing to that executable (which requires elevation of privilege), you get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

#### Solution

You could install `wkhtmltopdf` by running that **Installer** version and choosing the destination folder (let's say `C:\Program Files`). You will find the `wkhtmltopdf.exe` file that you need to add to your configuration inside the `bin` folder. Hence, you should use as follows:

```py
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=r'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe')
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf', configuration=config)
```

Another solution would be to download the `7z Archive` version, extract the files, in which you'll find `wkhtmltopdf.exe` under the `bin` folder as well.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue when I had not gone through the full installation of the wkpdftohtml library. Once it was unpacked, this ran without need for elevation.