# Keep getting "307 Temporary Redirect" before returning status 200 hosted on FastAPI + uvicorn + Docker app - how to return status 200?

Tags: python, redirect, fastapi, http-status-code-307

Edit:

I found the problem but not sure why this happens. Whenever I query: `http://localhost:4001/hello/` with the "`/`" in the end - I get a proper 200 status response.
I do not understand why.

Original Post:

Whenever I send a query to my app - I keep getting a 307 redirect.
How to get my app to return regular status 200 instead of redirecting it through 307

This is the request output:

```
abm                  | INFO:     172.18.0.1:46476 - "POST /hello HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
abm                  | returns the apples data. nothing special here.
abm                  | INFO:     172.18.0.1:46480 - "POST /hello/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

pytest returns:

```
E       assert 307 == 200
E        +  where 307 = <Response [307]>.status_code

test_main.py:24: AssertionError
```

in my root dir: `/__init__.py` file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
# from .configs import cors
from .subapp import router_hello
from .potato import router_potato
from .apple import router_apple


abm = FastAPI(
    title = "ABM"
)

# potato.add_middleware(cors)
abm.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

abm.include_router(router_hello.router)
abm.include_router(router_potato.router)
abm.include_router(router_apple.router)

@abm.post("/test", status_code = 200)
def test():
    print('test')
    return 'test'
```

`/subapp/router_hello.py` file:

```
router = APIRouter(
    prefix='/hello',
    tags=['hello'],
)

@router.post("/", status_code = 200)
def hello(req: helloBase, apple: appleHeader = Depends(set_apple_header), db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> helloResponse:
    db_apple = apple_create(apple, db, req.name)
    if db_apple:
        return set_hello_res(db_apple.potato.api, db_apple.name, 1)
    else:
        return "null"
```

in `/Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "abm:abm", "--reload", "--proxy-headers", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4001", "--forwarded-allow-ips", "*", "--log-level", "debug"]
```

I tried with and without `"--forwarded-allow-ips", "*"` part.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It happens because the exact path defined by you for your view is
`yourdomainname/hello/`, so when you hit it without `/` at the end, it first attempts to get to that path but as it is not available it checks again after appending `/` and gives a redirect `status code 307` and then when it finds the actual path it returns the status code that is defined in the `function/view` linked with that path, i.e `status code 200` in your case.

You can also read more about the issue here:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2060#issuecomment-834868906

Comment: +1. for some odd reason when I was testing my API locally it was fine, but when deployed to AWS Lambda, i was getting infinite redirects. Thanks!

Comment: Since this is an issue with FastAPI in my case, I just removed the '/' at the end, and it solved my issue. Not sure whether everyone can do that :) FYI, locally, this works just fine; the issue arises when we deploy to AWS Lambda.