# How to send Bearer token from React to FastAPI?

Tags: reactjs, axios, get, fastapi

I am using React in Front and FastAPI in back to authenticate users, but every time I try to get user information I get a 401 (Not authorized) error. Here is my React component to handle user context:

```js
// src.context.UserContext.jsx
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = (props) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("awesomeUserToken"));

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      };

      try {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/users/me", {}, config);
        localStorage.setItem("awesomeUserToken", token);
      } catch (error) {
        setToken(null);
        localStorage.setItem("awesomeUserToken", token);
      }
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[token, setToken]}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And here's my API route:

```py
# src.user.routes.py
@router.get("/me/", response_model=user_schemas.User)
async def get_user(
    current_user: user_schemas.User = _fastapi.Depends(
        user_services.get_current_user)
):
    return current_user
```

```py
# src.user.services.py
async def get_current_user(
    token: str = _fastapi.Depends(oauth2_scheme),
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(get_db)
):
    try:
        payload = _jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=["HS256"])
        user = db.query(user_models.User).get(payload["id"])
    except:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=401, detail="Invalid username or password")

    return user_schemas.User.model_validate(user)
```

Comment: What parts of the chain have you confirmed? Have you made sure that `token` is what you expect it to be on the server side? Have you confirmed that `payload['id']` is what you expact? Have you confirmed that `user` is what you expect? Have you looked at the request in your browser's dev tools to see that the `Authorization` header has been included as you expect?

Comment: We don't need to send a user, just a header with Authentication: "Bearer" + token. I checked it with Postman and the response is ok. I think the problem is in React or axios

Comment: Yes, my point was whether you actually got the expected `user` from your server side authentication. Compare the headers sent in the network request in your browser to what you're sending with Postman - if you believe it's a client side issue, then that should indicate where the problem is.

Comment: Make sense, thanks. But with Postman I send `curl --location 'http://localhost:8000/api/users/me' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'`
And the response is ok. I checked my token and it's the same, and with Axios I sent:  `axios.get("/api/users/me", config)` with headers and auth in config like I showed in publication but the response is 401, and I don't really know what the error is :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem

It turns out that my API route in FastAPI is `@router.get("/me/")` (with the final slash), but I was sending the request to `axios.get("/api/users/me", {}, config);` (without the slash), so FastAPI checks again after adding / and gives a 307 redirect status code that doesn't contain the headers.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70354027/8929988
And: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2060#issuecomment-834868906